# Is it possible to override a Promise chain that has already been declared?

Tags: javascript, html, promise

I have a save function which behaves asynchronously, thus I'm using promises. A main save event will come in and gets certain `then` and `catch` handler attached to them once and only once. For my code example, that will happen in the `importantSave` method. Now there may be any number of other save calls that get called later, and you can refer to the `sideSave` method.

Is there a way to make the `then` and `catch` handlers in the `importantSave` method wait for all of the side saves to resolve/reject before they are called, even though they are set up first?

For example, I have the following code:

```
class Adapter {
    promise;
    next_attempt;

    attempt() {
        if ( this.promise && this.promise.isPending() ) {
            this.next_attempt = this.attempt.bind( this );
            return this.promise.then( ()=> {
                if ( this.next_attempt ) {
                    return this.next_attempt();
                }
            } );
        } else {
            this.promise = new Promise( resolve=> {
                setTimeout( resolve, 3000 );
            } );

            return this.promise;
        }
    }
}
const adapter = new Adapter();

function importantSave() {
    adapter.attempt()
        .then( ()=> {
            console.log( 'Hello from the important save!' );
        } );
}

function sideSave() {
    adapter.attempt()
        .then( ()=> {
            console.log( 'Hello from the side save!' );
        } );
}

// the important save which sets up its then and catches, but wants to be called after all have finished
importantSave();

// any number of side saves, but will only be called with the last side save
sideSave();
sideSave();
sideSave();
```

Is there a way to change this so that if the `then` in importantSave is actually ran after any `thens` in the sideSave calls? My real world example will call the save function 3 times with a delay in between each call and will only reject if all 3 fail. If another call to save happens before all 3 fail, I want the newest call to be the "next_attempt", overwriting any other attempts to save while the first one was still pending. If the original call failed to save, but one of the "sideSave" calls passed, I want the `importantSave` to be fulfilled, thus fall into the then, not the catch that the original one failed.

Comment: Note that you will overwrite `this.next_attempt` when it already has a value, and you never clear it. Also note that it is bad practice to make your code dependent on something like `isPending()`. One should never need to check the state of a promise, other than using things like `then`, or derived methods.

Answer (score 1):

The way that this is commonly done, is with `Promise.all`.

Add all the promises you need to resolve in an array and pass it as argument:

```
Promise.all([importantSave(), sideSave(), sideSave(), sideSave()]).then(_ => {
    console.log('all done');
});
```

You can of course build the array dynamically:

```
var arr = [importantSave()];

arr.push(sideSave());
arr.push(sideSave());
arr.push(sideSave());

Promise.all(arr).then(_ => {
    console.log('all done');
});
```

If you need just one to fulfill, then use the opposite of those promises. You could use a helper function for that:

```
const invert = p => p.then(resp => { throw resp }).catch(err => err);
```

This function returns a promise that will reject when its argument fulfills, and vice versa.

Now you can do:

```
var arr = [importantSave()];

arr.push(sideSave());
arr.push(sideSave());
arr.push(sideSave());

invert(Promise.all(arr.map(invert))).then(_ => {
    console.log('one done');
});
```

Comment: This won't work. Maybe my description wasn't easy to understand, but the `sideSaves` come in dynamically and from different areas of my code. You can't know how many saves will come in before attaching the original `then`. To visualize this, imagine the code:

```var arr = [importantSave()];

setTimeout(()=>{
 arr.push(sideSave());
}, 1000);

setTimeout(()=>{
 arr.push(sideSave());
}, 2000);

Promise.all(arr).then(_ => {
 console.log('all done');
});```

The Promise.all will resolve DIRECTLY after the importantSave, but will ignore the sideSaves in the window timeouts.

Comment: Yes, you should of course ignore the resolving promise, as you don't know how many you will still add. Your real promise, becomes Promise.all. Your question is ambiguous, because one side you say you want to wait, but also say you want to resolve as soon as one fulfills.

Comment: What really is your need? To retry an operation 3 times and only give up if all of them fail? You write *will only reject if all 3 fail*, so why then wait for all when you have fulfillment?